# What is the lightest possible way to record a screencast with ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, screen-capture, screencasts

I would like to capture a sreencast at 60fps.

I tried with this:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -c:a pcm_s16le -f x11grab -r 60 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 out.mkv
```

However it caused some noticeable jerkyness while capturing, and didn't seem to go over 35 fps, even without desktop compositing (compton).

Entire sections of of the audio and video were also missing, causing large jumps and desynchronization of the audio and video.

I'm running Archlinux with Openbox on an intel Xeon quad core CPU. (not sure of the exact model, but I can find out if needed)

Is there a method with less overhead?

---

As requested in the comments:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -t 10 -f null -

ffmpeg version 2.4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 28 2014 18:38:33 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-shared --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-decoder=atrac3 --enable-decoder=atrac3p --enable-dxva2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-gray --enable-ladspa --enable-libaacplus --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libutvideo --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-swresample --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
[x11grab @ 0xc32f20] device: :0.0 -> display: :0.0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 1920 height: 1080
[x11grab @ 0xc32f20] shared memory extension found
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1417394813.860186, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1920x1080, -2147483 kb/s, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 60 tbc
No pixel format specified, rgb24 for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.2, 4:4:4 8-bit
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264rgb), rgb24, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264rgb
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264rgb))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  207 fps= 23 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:08.91 bitrate=N/A    
video:3932kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] frame I:1     Avg QP: 0.00  size:644758
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] frame P:206   Avg QP: 0.00  size: 16415
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] mb P  I16..4: 71.2%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:28.6%
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] coded y,u,v intra: 0.2% 0.3% 0.3% inter: 0.5% 0.5% 0.5%
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 99%  1%  0%  0%
[libx264rgb @ 0xc49c40] kb/s:3605.53
```

Comment: You may have to reduce your `-video_size` and `-framerate` if performance is not satisfactory. You'll need to perform some benchmarks to find out where the bottleneck is. Please show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -t 10 -f null -` This will indicate if the encoder can reach your desired frame rate without the overhead of writing the output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Edited. It never even reached 30 fps :/ Isn't there some way of dumping the raw video while recording and then encoding later?

Comment: Yes. You can test the theoretical speed by removing `-c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast` from the `null` command, however I'm not sure how IO is going to affect the speed when you do output to a file with `-c:v rawvideo output.nut` (you can calculate the rawvideo size first if you feel like figuring it out).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Huh.. It still didn't go over 35 fps. Is this normal? I thought 60 fps wouldn't be too hard..

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Oh yes, I'm using the `ffmpeg-full` package from the aur in case that matters.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ffmpeg from Extra goes at about 50 fps without encoding or writing. When writing it goes at about 25. I guess I have a really slow hard drive?

Comment: I don't know. Now that you're using the package from Extra you have to retest the first command I provided then try outputting. You could also attempt to compile `ffmpeg` from current git master (no need to install) and test it.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard With ffmpeg from Extra, the first command (encoding but not writing) goes at 29 fps. If I turn off compton it goes at 31 fps.